# SQL code Interpretation "mod" and "CStr"

Tags: sql, interpretation

I've been given an example of SQL code and I need to understand what this is doing before I convert it to another language.

Can someone explain to me in English what this code does please?

`=IIF(Fields!Time.Value\60 < 10, "0" + CStr(Fields!Time.Value\60), CStr(Fields!Time.Value\60)) 
 + ":" + 
 IIF(Fields!Time.Value mod 60 < 10, "0" + FormatNumber(Fields!Time.Value mod 60,0), FormatNumber(Fields!Time.Value mod 60,0))`

Many Many Thanks

Comment: Is that code supposed to be SQL??? Far from ANSI SQL anyway, so you'd better tag dbms product to get better attention.

Comment: Thats what I was told - I'll fix the tags if I can

Comment: So from what context did you get that statement from? Some reporting tool that uses VB style scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taking a time (in seconds), and converting it to the format "mm:ss". For what it is worth, this looks more like VB script than SQL. Anyway, [`Cstr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) simply converts to string, [`mod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) gives the remainder of a division, e.g. `16 mod 10` gives you `6`, `26 mod 10` would also give you 6.

The first part is using `Fields!Time.Value/60` to get the time in minutes, then when this is number is less than 10, appending a 0 to the start:

```
    |   If seconds less than 10 |  Append 0 to left of seconds   |  else just use seconds    |

=IIF( Fields!Time.Value\60 < 10 , "0" + CStr(Fields!Time.Value\60), CStr(Fields!Time.Value\60))
```

The next part basically does the same with the seconds, part, but uses mod to get the number of seconds, for example, 97 seconds needs to be broken down to "01:37", so `97 / 60` is used to get the 1, then because this is less than 10, "0" is prepended to it, then `97 mod 60` is used to get the seconds, which gives 37, since this is over 10 nothing is prepended.

Comment: Thank you - exactly the response I needed